# Creating Sub Folders in VBA

Tags: vba

Having some problem with my macro which I can't seem to figure out :(

I have a main folder called "Divisions" in my desktop. I would like to create two types of sub folders - Individual Division folders (e.g. Div1, Div2, Div3) and Individual Officer folders (e.g. Div1_Alice, Div2_Bert, Div3_Cindy).

It should be arranged in this way: Desktop>Division folder >Individual Division folders> Individual Officer folders.

I have created the macro below with the help of a [Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5MYtAHutRQ&t=68s&ab_channel=PK%3AAnExcelExpert) but it dosen't seem to work when I try to create two types of sub folders at once.
Would appreciate any help please!

(Btw the status column is just to update whether the folder has been created or not)

| Name | Division | Name + Division | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | Div1 | Div1_Alice |  |
| Bert | Div2 | Div2_Bert |  |
| Cindy | Div3 | Div3_Cindy |  |

> ```
> Sub Create_Multiple_Folders()
>
>     Dim sh As Worksheet
>
>     Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
>
>     Dim sub_folder_path As String
>
>     Dim i As Integer
>
>     For i = 2 To sh.Range("C" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
>
>         sub_folder_path = sh.Range("E2").Value & "\" & sh.Range("B" & i).Value & "\" & sh.Range("C" & i).Value
>
>         If Dir(sub_folder_path, vbDirectory) = "" Then
>
>             MkDir (sub_folder_path)
>
>             sh.Range("D" & i).Value = "Folder Created"
>
>         Else
>
>             sh.Range("D" & i).Value = "Folder already available"
>
>         End If
>
>     Next i
>
> End Sub
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to create the directory structure sequentially, by levels:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Create_Multiple_Folders()

    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim sub_folder_path As String

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 2 To sh.Range("C" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ' make 1st level - Divisions/DivN
        sub_folder_path = sh.Range("E2").Value & "\" & sh.Range("B" & i).Value
        If Dir(sub_folder_path, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir sub_folder_path
        
        ' make 2nd level - Divisions/DivN/DivN_Name
        sub_folder_path = sub_folder_path & "\" & sh.Range("C" & i).Value
        If Dir(sub_folder_path, vbDirectory) = "" Then
            MkDir sub_folder_path
            sh.Range("D" & i).Value = "Folder Created"
        Else
            sh.Range("D" & i).Value = "Folder already available"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Алексей Р, this works perfectly, thanks for explaining and the solution!